# How to abbreviate special words for IEEEtran.bst

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, ieeetran

According to `IEEEtran_bst_HOWTO`:

> `IEEEabrv.bib` contains the abbreviated form of **the journal and
>   magazine names**. Recommended for work that is to be submitted to the
>   IEEE.

Both it is not able to abbreviate common words in each entry.

Is there any way to automatically abbreviate special words (like `Conference: Conf.` or `International: Intl.`) within the references?

As a matter of `MWE`, assume following files:

The main file:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10pt, conference]{IEEEconf}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}



\title{My Title*}

\author{Guy$^{1}$
    \thanks{*This work was not supported by any organization}% <-this % stops a space
    \thanks{$^{1}$Guy is with Hell, {\tt\small guy@hell.edu}}%
}

\begin{document}

    \maketitle
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \pagestyle{empty}

    \begin{abstract}

        ABSTRACT

    \end{abstract}


\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranS}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,references}{}

\end{document}
```

And its corresponding `*.bib` file:

```
@inproceedings{lau2011automatic,
    title={Automatic learning of pushing strategy for delivery of irregular-shaped objects},
    author={Lau, Manfred and Mitani, Jun and Igarashi, Takeo},
    booktitle={Robotics and Automation (ICRA), 2011 IEEE International Conference on},
    pages={3733--3738},
    year={2011},
    organization={IEEE}
}
```

This is how `LaTeX` generates:

[image]

Is it possible to apply target abbreviations (as acquire following result) without manual changes onto `*.bib` file?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got an answer with manual changes in the `bib` file.

In [JabRef](https://www.jabref.org), there is the possibility to abbreviate the journal titles based on preconfigured lists. A long how-to is available at https://help.jabref.org/en/JournalAbbreviations

### Setup JabRef

1. Download [journal_abbreviations_ieee.txt](https://github.com/JabRef/reference-abbreviations/blob/master/journals/journal_abbreviations_ieee.txt)
2. Start JabRef
3. Navigate to Options, Manage Journal Abbreviations
4. At the lower section "External files", click on the "Browse" button (before "Download")
5. Browse for `journal_abbreviations_ieee.txt` and click "OK"
6. Click "OK"

### Use JabRef for abbreviation

1. Open the `bib` file in JabRef
2. Now doubleclick the article, where you want to use the abbreviation.
3. The entry editor opens
4. Ensure that the tab "Required fields" is selected
5. Right of the field "Journal", there is a button "Toggle abbreviation". Press it.
6. Now, the abbreviation should be in the field "Journal". If not, then the journal name is not in the abbreviation list
7. Repeat these steps for all entries.
8. Save the bibliography

[image: Toogle Journal Abbreviation]

### Notes

IEEE uses strings for the abbreviations. Accoring to the docmentation, they have to be included using `\bibliopgraphy{IEEEabrv}`.

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,mybibfile}
```

JabRef's internal data model is BibTeX. There is no additional database or conversion involved.

There is also "Tools -> Unabbreviate Journal Names", but I could not find an option for "Abbreviate Journal Names".

Comment: You're talking about adding journals, whereas my question is about abbreviating some special word. I don't understand how your answer address it.

Comment: @Roboticist I refined my answer by splitting in installation and usage. Further, I added an animation.